# Homotopy group of geometric realization is isomorphic to the original homotopy group.

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

It is a fact that if you take a Kan complex $X$, its homotopy group is isomorphic to the homotopy group of $\left|X \right|$, the geometric realization of $X$ as topological space.

I'm looking for proof of this fact. Thank you!

Comment: You probably mean Kan complex, not simplicial set.

Comment: @NoelLundström yeah you're right, thanks!

Comment: This is an important foundational result in simplicial homotopy theory. What definitions are you using and what are you willing to assume? It is easy to give proofs that are ultimately circular if you are not careful.

Comment: See Proposition 11.1 of http://dodo.pdmi.ras.ru/~topology/books/goerss-jardine.pdf and the discussion afterwards for a proof.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ashwin lyengar in the comments, this is an consequence of Proposition 11.1 in Chapter I of Goerss and Jardine's book *Simplicial Homotopy Theory*, as explained in the paragraph immediately following the proposition, using the fact that the canonical map $X\mapsto S|X|$ (which is the unit of the adjunction between geometric realisation and the singular set functor) is a weak equivalence whenever $X$ is Kan, in the sense that it induces an isomorphism on all simplicial homotopy groups.